# alignment sequence in large protein sequence

Tags: java, sequence, bioinformatics

I have a large protein sequence which is approximetaly 5000 so I put it in a text file (p_sqn.txt) and I have the following sequence

for example ; SDJGSKLDJGSNMMUWEURYI

I have to find that percentage identity scoring function, so for that I have to find the most similar sequence in the protein sequence. (protein_sequence.txt)

Comment: Which kind of algorithem do you want to use?

Comment: what is percentage identity scoring function? We are programmers and no knowledge of bioinformatics :)

Comment: What's the metrics for similarity?

Comment: May be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with checking the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) at every point in the sequence.

With a length of just 5000, it won't take very long (milliseconds) to do the pass.

Fortunately, the [Apache commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides the [`StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) utility method. With this, the code would be just a few lines:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

String protein; // the full sequence
String part; // your search string
int bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int bestLocation = 0;
String bestSeqence = "";
for (int i = 0; i < protein.length() - part.length(); i++) {
    String sequence = protein.substring(i, part.length());
    int score = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(sequence, part);
    if (score < bestScore) {
        bestScore = score;
        bestLocation = i;
        bestSeqence = sequence;
    }
}

// at this point in the code, the "best" variables will have data about the best match.
```

fyi, a score of zero means an exact match was found.

---

To make it easy to read the file in, you can use [Apache common-io library](http://commons.apache.org/io/) utility method [`FileUtils.readFileToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29), like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

String protein = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/some/path/to/myproteinfile.txt"));
```

Comment: at String protein;  must be the text file for the protein sequence. may i use the bufferedreader for that

Comment: No. Apache has another library to easily deal in files. I'll edit the answer. To answer your previous comment that you deleted, go to the link in the answer and follow to download and put the jar in your classpath

Comment: You need to add the jar to your project's classpath. If you're using Eclipse, modify your "build path". Google for more help.

Comment: I don't know anything about your dev environment, so I can't help. There are loads of tutorials on the web that can help, so google to figure it out.

Comment: Why don't you search for an answer on SO for your setup question - there's bound to be one. If not (unlikely) post another question here with the specifics of your dev env and the error message you're getting.